# ApplicationRunner NoSuchBeanException on Repository interface

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I defined this model class:

```
package test.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Property {  
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  private String streetName;

  public String getStreetName() {
    return streetName;
  }

  public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
    this.streetName = streetName;
  }
}
```

I created a repository class so I can do operations on the database:

```
package test.repository;

import test.model.Property;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PropertyRepository extends CrudRepository<Property,Long> {
}
```

Next, I have an application runner class:

```
package test.cron;

import test.model.Property;
import test.repository.PropertyRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@ComponentScan("test.repository")
@Service
public class MyRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
  @Autowired
  PropertyRepository propertyRepository;

  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
    System.out.println("In MyRunner.run()");
    Property prop = new Property();
    prop.setStreetName("Main street");
    propertyRepository.save(prop);
  }
}
```

Here is my main application which uses the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation:

```
package test.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan({"test.cron","test.repository"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  /** Main method */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

When I run the application, I am getting this error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field propertyRepository in test.cron.MyRunner required a bean of type 'test.repository.PropertyRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'test.repository.PropertyRepository' in your configuration.
```

From what I am reading, spring is supposed to create the instance of the repository.

What am I missing?

Comment: remove `@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan({"test.cron","test.repository"})`, its not required spring boot will take care, also if your project build is not war file remove `SpringBootServletInitializer` as well

Comment: I added the EnableJpaRepositories and ComponentScan based on the answer by Ravid luz below.  My application did not have those originally and it generated the exception. I am using a war file.

Comment: I recreated the project using your application structure, its working fine, I removed `@EnableJpaRepositories @ComponentScan({"test.cron","test.repository"})` and kept `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Comment: I tried removing the annotations and I don't get an error.  But, the property object is not created in the database.  I think MyRunner did not run since I did not get the `In MyRunner.run()` output.

Comment: move your `TestApplication` to top level package i.e. test, your application runner will work

Comment: Interesting, that worked.  Why would it care what the package structure is?

Comment: spring boot automatically scan's the package below the parent package and do the required configuration, that's the beauty of spring boot. please accept the answer, if this resolve your issue.

Comment: Now, I have the opposite problem.  I am getting the MyRunner.run method called twice and my database has two rows of the same property object.  Any idea why it would do that?  Also, this discussion is in the comments, so I can't accept it.  Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: remove @ComponentScan from your MyRunner class

Comment: Tomcat must have not been cleaning up the code correctly when it reloaded the war file.  I deleted the war file and the test webapp directory, uploaded a new war, and restarted Tomcat.  It worked correctly this time.  I only got one copy of the property in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following it will resolve the issue

remove `@EnableJpaRepositories @ComponentScan({"test.cron","test.repository"})`, its not required spring boot will take care, also if your project build is not war file remove `SpringBootServletInitializer` as well.

move your `TestApplication` to top level package i.e. test, your application runner will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your main class.
Regardless, spring initializes
all of it’s beans one startup. If your repository isn’t recognised as a bean it means that spring hasn’t canned it. Therefore, you need to add a @ComponentScan to tell spring to explicitly scan your repository class.

Comment: I added the EnableJpaRepositories and ComponentScan annotations to my main application class and that did not make a difference.  I updated my question above and included my main class as well.  Please take a look.